# How do I add custom properties to an AD group in Windows?

Tags: windows, active-directory, ldap

I'd like to know how to script this. Also, is there an out of the box GUI tool that will let me do this?

Comment: Check out [Admod](http://www.joeware.net/freetools/tools/admod/index.htm) and this [blog post](http://blog.joeware.net/2006/08/25/553/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you referring to the CustomField attributes that exchange adds when you extend the AD Schema?  If so, then you could use [ADSIEdit](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc773354.aspx).

If you want to make your own fields then I think your options would be extend the schema or possibly use ADAM.

I haven't used ADAM for Groups, but I think its still possible.

There are some basic scripts on accessing groups at [Microsoft's Script Center](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/scriptcenter/scripts/default.mspx?mfr=true).