# Set Access to dropdownlist items based on the User's Active Directory Group

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-services, active-directory, windows-authentication

Background: I have a webForm app that registers a user in the database based on the information provided with a web service, auto-generates a random password and username, and e-mails the user a link to take an application based on the marketing company selected.

Questions:

- How do I get only the currently logged in user's groups to show up under the MarketingCo_DropDownList

Each user allowed access to the system will have membership in at least one of the marketing groups as defined by the web.config.  For example, a user that is currently logged in and belongs to the BIG group under location "alg\ACOMP_user_BIG", will only be able to see BIG in the Marketing Company drop down list.  A user that is currently logged in and belongs to the NIS group located under "alg\ACOMP_user_NIS" will only be able to see NIS in the Marketing Company drop down list.

Here's a screenshot of the front end:
[image: web app screenshot]

Here's my best guess (located under Private Sub GetMarketingCompanies() method in default.aspx.vb):

```
    If InStr(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Groups = "AMG", item.MarketingCompanyShort = "AMG", CompareMethod.Text) Then
            marketingCo.Items.Add(String.Format("{0} | {1}", item.MarketingCompanyShort, item.MarketingCompanyName))

            For Each item In ac1
                 marketingCo.Items.Add(String.Format("{0} | {1}", item.MarketingCompanyShort, item.MarketingCompanyName))
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

I've been going off the code from [Wrox's Windows Authentication Tutorial](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/Section/ASP-NET-3-5-Windows-Based-Authentication.id-310905.html) but it's not thorough enough for what I'm trying to do.

Web.config file (pertinent code displayed only):

```
 <authentication mode="Windows"/>
   <authorization>            
    <allow users="alg\bmccarthy, alg\phoward" />               
    <allow roles="alg\ACOMP_user_Admin" />
    <allow roles="alg\ACOMP_user_AMG" />
    <allow roles="alg\ACOMP_user_BIG" />
    <allow roles="alg\ACOMP_user_NIS" />
    <allow roles="alg\ACOMP_user_GLA" />
    <allow roles="alg\ACOMP_user_PIP" />
    <allow roles="alg\ACOMP_user_PSM" />
    <allow roles="alg\ACOMP_user_PAM" />
    <allow roles="alg\ACOMP_user_ANN" />
    <allow roles="alg\ACOMP_user_AAM" />
    <allow roles="alg\ACOMP_user_MWM" /> 
    <allow roles="alg\ACOMP_user_GIM" />
    <deny users="*" />        
</authorization> 
   <bindings>
   <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IAcompService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
      openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
      allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
      maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
      messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
      useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
          realm="" />
          <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
        </security>
      </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <client>
  <endpoint address="http://172.17.1.40/aCompService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
    bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IAcompService" contract="aComp_ServiceReference.IAcompService"
    name="BasicHttpBinding_IAcompService" />
  </client>
 </system.serviceModel>
```

default.aspx.vb code w/ the GetMarketingCompanies() and Page_Load() Methods where the application retrieves MarketingCompanies from the webservice and loads it into the dropdownlist through an array:

```
Private Sub GetMarketingCompanies()
    Try
        Dim ac1 As Array
        ac1 = proxy.GetMarketingCompanyNames("acompUser", "acompPass!")


        ' If InStr(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Groups = "AMG", item.MarketingCompanyShort = "AMG", CompareMethod.Text) Then
        '  marketingCo.Items.Add(String.Format("{0} | {1}", item.MarketingCompanyShort, item.MarketingCompanyName))

        ' if current user role="alg\ACOMP_user_BIG" display BIG MarketingCo.Item '
        ' if current user role="alg\ACOMP_user_NIS" display NIS MarketingCo.Item '
        ' if current user role="alg\ACOMP_user_GLA" display GLA MarketingCo.Item '
        ' if current user role="alg\ACOMP_user_PIP" display PIP MarketingCo.Item '
        ' if current user role="alg\ACOMP_user_PSM" display PSM MarketingCo.Item '
        ' if current user role="alg\ACOMP_user_PAM" display PAM MarketingCo.Item '
        ' if current user role="alg\ACOMP_user_ANN" display ANN MarketingCo.Item '
        ' if current user role="alg\ACOMP_user_AAM" display AAM MarketingCo.Item '
        ' if current user role="alg\ACOMP_user_MWM" display MWM MarketingCo.Item '
        ' if current user role="alg\ACOMP_user_GIM" display GIM MarketingCo.Item '

        ' if current user = alg\ACOMP_user_Admin display all marketing companies in drop down list '
        For Each item In ac1
            marketingCo.Items.Add(String.Format("{0} | {1}", item.MarketingCompanyShort, item.MarketingCompanyName))
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load, Me.Load, Me.Load
    If Not lbCarriers.Items.Count > 0 Then
        GetCarriers()
        GetMarketingCompanies()
    End If
End Sub
```

Default.aspx code where the marketingCo drop down list is defined:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="style3">
            Marketing Co (auto-populated):
        </td>
        <td bgcolor="#ffffff" class="style8">
            <asp:DropDownList ID="marketingCo" runat="server" Height="23px" 
                Width="250px">
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </td>
    </tr>
        <td bgcolor="#ffffff" class="style6">
            <asp:Button ID="Send_Button" runat="server"  Text="Send Invitation" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The Web service returns an Array of Strings w/ MarketingCompanyShort and MarketingCompanyName that are added as items to the drop down list
Web Service XSD File Code:

```
<xs:element name="ArrayOfMarketingCompany" type="tns:ArrayOfMarketingCompany" nillable="true"/>
<xs:complexType name="MarketingCompany">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="MarketingCompanyId" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element name="MarketingCompanyName" type="xs:string" nillable="true" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element name="MarketingCompanyShort" type="xs:string" nillable="true" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Thanks for looking!

If you have any helpful links or suggestions, I'll give you an up-vote!

Comment: Can you parameterize your service call to bring back items only for specific group and send current users group as parameter?

Comment: @Subhash, I'm not sure what you mean but I was thinking I can do this by editing the GetMarketingCompanies() method.

Comment: Yeah, so using information from here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.aspx you can get current user's group and change your GetMarketingCompanies method to accept group as parameter and send only required information. This will save your bandwidth as well :)

Comment: @Subhash, while that code example is some-what helpful, it doesn't answer my question. What part of that long page of code could I use? Can you provide some VB.NET code in an answer so I can up-vote it?

Comment: so do I use something like this.... If InStr(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent.Groups = "AMG", item.MarketingCompanyShort = "AMG", CompareMethod.Text) Then ... It's got an error on it. I'm not sure about the correct syntax for this.

Comment: Any other suggestions? How do I start a bounty for this question? I don't see the link to start a bounty on here :(

Comment: So the webservice returns all of the MarketingCompanies?  How do you determine what marketingcompanies should be shown to those groups?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IdentityReference.Value returns the current user's SID's (ex: S-1-5-32-544) not the group name (ex: Acomp_user_BIG).

You need to use IdentityReference.Translate to convert the
Security Identifiers (SID's) that WindowsIdentiy.Groups returns into NTAccounts

Here is code that will output all the group names that the current user belongs to:

```
Public ReadOnly Property Groups As IdentityReferenceCollection
    Get
        Dim identityReferenceCollection As IdentityReferenceCollection
        Dim identityReference As IdentityReference
        identityReferenceCollection = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Groups
        Dim strGroupName As String
        Dim mcisloaded As Boolean

        ' Translate the current user's active directory groups 
        For Each identityReference In identityReferenceCollection
            Dim mktGroup As IdentityReference = identityReference.Translate(GetType(NTAccount))
            ' MsgBox(mktGroup.Value)

            strGroupName = mktGroup.Value.ToString
         Next    

    End Get
End Property
```

Comment: That's a property. The Get method on a Property must return a value. Type Return irc before the End Get.

Comment: thanks! @Cwoo, Where/How do i check the trace listeners in the System.Diagnostics.Debug.Listeners collection? I am trying to see what values are returned for the active directory groups. I added a MsgBox(account.Value) and no msgBox comes up

Comment: You wont see a message box if your running the code straight on a web server rather than through Visual studio. Id recommend just putting in some breakpoints and running your app through Visual Studio instead of this guess work! That being said you can use something like this too see debug output from hosted: http://tanzimsaqib.com/blog/105/debugging-asp-net-applications-interactively-on-production/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that I quite follow; are you matching each group name to a particular marketing company. In that this link isnt  saved in Active Directory any place, just by you matching up the text of each?

If thats the case I think you just want to check what groups are returned by the windows itentitfy. So somthing like this?

```
For Each UserGroup in WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Groups
  If UserGroup.Value = "AMG" Then
    Dim Company= ac1.Cast(Of [TypeOfItemHere]).Where(Function(ac) ac.MarketingCompanyShort = "AMG").FirstOrDefault
    If Company IsNot Nothing Then
      marketingCo.Items.Add(String.Format("{0} | {1}", Company.MarketingCompanyShort, Company.MarketingCompanyName))
    End If
  End If
Next
```

...And so on for the other groups. That being said it would probably be better to pass the WindowsIdentitiy.GetCurrent().Groups to your service instead and do the filtering there.

Comment: @Cwoo, thanks for your response! Each user allowed access to the system will have membership in at least one of the marketing groups as defined by the web.config. For example, a user that is in the BIG group under location "alg\ACOMP_user_BIG", will only be able to see BIG in the Marketing Company drop down list.  A user that is in the NIS group located under "alg\ACOMP_user_NIS" will only be able to see NIS in the Marketing Company drop down list.

Comment: Yes, each group name matches up to a marketing company. I need the code to check the current logged in user's groups and see if they belong under alg\ACOMP_user_NIS, alg\ACOMP_user_BIG, etc... under the alg directory there are several different groups, would it be better if we put all the groups under one directory like alg\ACOMP\user_NIS or what would be the most efficient way to reference and identify each marketing company?

Comment: I don't know. If all the groups you are interested in are in the same directory you can use the DirectoryEntry / DirectorySearcher classes to find those groups. Maybe you could look at adding a custom property to those groups, a google search suggests its possible but I have no experience of trying it (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/202736/how-do-i-add-custom-properties-to-an-ad-group-in-windows). It might be easier to just put the "which group  ties to which Marketing Company" information into a database table (Your service could reference that table to return the filtered company list)?

Comment: @Cwoo, I'm getting an error on "ac1.Where" from this code in the VS2010. What should I put instead?  Intellisence gives me the following options for the ac1 marketing companies array - getlength, getlowerbound, getupperbound, length, rank, setvalue. "foreach" should be "For Each" with a space. The For Each loop should end with a Next Clause

Comment: Sorry I didn't type any of that into Visual Studio, missed ac1 was an Array and not a List. The Array does not implement the required interface to use LINQ extension methods. Try this instead: ac1.Cast(Of *YourTypeHere*).Where(Function(ac) ac.MarketingCompanyShort = "AMG").FirstOrDefault  - With *YourTypeHere* is the type your service is returning. That or you could change your service to return a list instead of an array!

Comment: I get the following Error: Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Where' can be called with these arguments:Extension method 'Public Function Where(predicate As System.Func(Of String, Integer, Boolean)) As System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of String)' defined in 'System.Linq.Enumerable': Nested function does not have a signature that is compatible with delegate 'System.Func(Of String, Integer, Boolean)'.
    Extension method 'Public Function Where(predicate As System.Func(Of String, Boolean))

Comment: As System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of String)' defined in 'System.Linq.Enumerable': 'MarketingCompanyShort' is not a member of 'String'.

Comment: Did you type ac1.Cast(Of String).Where ...  ? Your service is returning a collection of a class objects with the call to GetMarketingCompanyNames. Get the name of the class object and put that class name in the .Cast(Of ) bit. Or is your service just returning an Array of Objects and you where accessing the properties MarketingCompanyShort and MarketingCompanyName in an untyped fashion?

Comment: @Cwoo, Yes, I used ac1.Cast(Of String).Where". The Web service returns an Array of Strings w/ MarketingCompanyShort and MarketingCompanyName that are added as items to the listbox. Here's the original code:            Dim ac1 As Array --
            ac1 = proxy.GetMarketingCompanyNames("test", "test") --

            For Each item In ac1 --
                marketingCo.Items.Add(String.Format("{0} | {1}", item.MarketingCompanyShort, item.MarketingCompanyName)) --

            Next --
        Catch ex As Exception --
            MsgBox(ex.Message) --
        End Try

Comment: @Cwoo, I didn't write the web service. Where do I look to find out about the MarketingCompanyShort and MarketingCompanyName items? What do you mean in an untyped fashion? I am looking at the aCompService3.xsd file and it says Marketing Company is listed as a complexType and as an element. Clicking on it shows it contains MarketingCompanyId int, MarketingCompanyName String, MarketingCompanyShort string.

Comment: Here's the code for the Web Service XSD: <xs:element name="ArrayOfMarketingCompany" type="tns:ArrayOfMarketingCompany" nillable="true"/>
 <xs:complexType name="MarketingCompany">
  <xs:sequence>
   <xs:element name="MarketingCompanyId" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xs:element name="MarketingCompanyName" type="xs:string" nillable="true" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xs:element name="MarketingCompanyShort" type="xs:string" nillable="true" minOccurs="0"/>
  </xs:sequence>
 </xs:complexType>
 <xs:element name="MarketingCompany" type="tns:MarketingCompany" nillable="true"/>

Comment: Your service isn't returning an array of strings its returning an array of MarketingCompanys objects, you might be able to directly refer to that class. Your service, proxy, did you go through the "Add Service Reference" menu option to create that class? If you did you should be able to put somthing like  .Cast(Of NameSpaceofService.MarketingCompany). If you already have the namespace of the service imported you should be able to just type .Cast(Of MarketingCompany).

Comment: @Cwoo, Yes, I did "Add Service Reference" to create the class and have it imported into the default.aspx.vb file by the name of aComp_ServiceReference, so I'll use "Dim MarketingCo = ac1.Cast(Of MarketingCompany).Where(Function(ac) ac.MarketingCompanyShort = "AMG").FirstOrDefault" but then i get the following Error on marketingCo.Items.Add: 'Items' is not a member of  ACOMP_Invitation_Web_App.aComp_ServiceReference.MarketingCompany'. Any idea on how to fix that?

Comment: Heh, yea, sorry! I declared the local variable in the for each loop to be the same name as your combo box. I updated the answer but just call it something else.

Comment: @Cwoo, I tried that and there were no errors but the drop down list was completely blank. Perhaps I'm not referencing the active directory groups properly? the full name for the active directory is ALG.local/Groups/DMZ Web Groups/ACOMP/ACOMP_USER_ADMIN and for local testing i am using alg\bmccarthy and will be using algweb\bmccarthy when it is deployed but not sure if the groups are also alg\ACOMP_user_AMG or what.. perhaps the code is calling groups and then trying to match up just one value and it doesnt match up to anything?

Comment: Could be! Hard to say without running it. Just put a break point at the start of the foor loop and see what happens when its running. Are any groups returned? Does any of the groups description match up to "AMG"?, etc-

Comment: @Cwoo, No groups are returned. Which field does UserGroup.Value call? The active directories Description? I added "BIG" under description for acomp_user_BIG group and it still didn't display Marketing Company BIG, with UserGroupValue="BIG". Perhaps, I should just have the application display the UserGroup.Value For Each UserGroup In WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Groups so I can see the values the app is seeing so that I can reference them correctly. What do you recommend?

Comment: @Cwoo, I used For Each UserGroup In WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Groups MsgBox(UserGroup.Value) and get the following numbers: S-1-5-21-3794573037-2687555854-1483818651-513 S-1-1-0 S-1-5-32-545 S-1-5-4 S-1-2-1 S-1-5-11 S-1-5-15 S-1-2-0 S-1-5-21-3794573037-2687555854-1483818651-5076 S-1-5-21-3794573037-2687555854-1483818651-2813 S-1-5-21-3794573037-2687555854-1483818651-13102 S-1-5-21-3794573037-2687555854-1483818651-2851 S-1-5-21-3794573037-2687555854-1483818651-1401 S-1-5-21-3794573037-2687555854-1483818651-4526. UserGroup.Value returns the SID and does not call the group's name.

Comment: *sigh* ^^ I'm being wrong an awful lot here (sorry!), but at least your working through it I guess? You could leave it matching the sid but it would look pretty unsightly. Google suggested this for converting Sids to group names: http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/430823-can-convert-sid-group-name

Comment: @Cwoo, the code on that page didnt provide me with any values in a msg box: Dim irc As IdentityReferenceCollection
Dim ir As IdentityReference
irc = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Groups
For Each ir In irc
Dim account As IdentityReference =
ir.Translate(GetType(NTAccount))
MsgBox(account.Value)
Next

Comment: @Cwoo, I tried the code on http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/430823-can-convert-sid-group-name and I got the following error when trying to use the code Property 'Groups' doesn't return a value on all code paths. 
                A null reference exception could occur at run time when the 
                result is used. I posted it as an answer. Any ideas on how to fix that?